# Populating jqGrid with JSON return data and getting Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm trying to return some JSON from my Spring webapp using Jackson and parse it and load it into a jqGrid.

I've got the data coming back and visible in Chrome via the JSONViewer extension.  It looks correct to me.

Local tests with arraydata have been successful.

Here's my JSP/HTML/JS:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css' />

 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js'></script>

 <script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({        
        url:"formSubmit.html",
        datatype: "json",
        height: 700,
        width: 1100,
        colNames: ['ReqID', 'Family', 'ControlID', 'Name', 'Description', 'Category','Priority', 'Notes', 'Parent'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'reqID', index: 'reqID', width: 40 },
        { name: 'family', index: 'family', width: 100 },
        { name: 'controlID', index: 'controlID', width: 100 },
        { name: 'reqName', index: 'reqName', width: 175 },
        { name: 'requirement', index: 'requirement', width: 450,cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' } },
        { name: 'category', index: 'category', width: 100 },
        { name: 'priority', index: 'priority', width: 100 },
        { name: 'requirementNotes', index: 'requirementNotes', width: 100 },
        { name: 'parent', index: 'parent', width: 100 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        jsonReader : { repeatitems: false }
    });

    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

});
 </script>

<table id = 'list'></table>
```

Here's some data coming back from my Spring container using Jackson:

```
{
"total":"1",
"page":"1",
"records":"558",
"rows":[{
    "parent":"",
    "priority":"",
    "requirementNotes":"DummyData",
    "category":"DummyData",
    "family":"DummyData",
    "requirement":"DummyData",
    "reqID":"1",
    "controlID":"DummyData",
    "reqName":"DummyData"}]
}
```

I'm consistently getting back an Uncaught TypeError cannot read property '0' in undefined as my response in jquery.jqGrid.min.js:23 and I'm stumped.

Comment: it's very strange that the `url` option which you use in jqGrid has `.html` extension and contains (or generates) JSON data (response). Should the `url` be not URL to your MVC Controller? Another strange, but not critical thing is that you use CSS from jQuery UI 1.8.6, but JS from jQuery UI 1.8.17.

Comment: My Spring MVC controller's @RequestMapping points to a "virtual" html file.  I didn't expect this to be a problem...but at this point I'm anxious to eliminate variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can see from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Brent.htm), which uses the JSON data which you posted and your code, the jqGrid should work in general.

I can only repeat the same what I wrote already in my previous comment: the parameter `url:"formSubmit.html"` seems to me very suspected. If you call some dynamic components you URL should be  either without extension like "/myurl/" or with some other extension as '.html'. I recommend you to analyse the HTTP traffic with respect of Fiddler, Firebug or Developer Tools of IE or Chrome (look at "Network" Tab). Important can be not only the HTTP body, but the HTTP headers like "Content-Type".

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `root: "rows"` inside the jsonreader.