# jqGrid throws: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I found several other `Uncaught TypeError` based questions on SO but not this particular one, so I thought I'll put this up just in case anyone else has had this issue.

My jqGrid works absolutely fine however I keep seeing this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined jquery.jqGrid.min.js:423
```

I checked and this corresponds to line **4364** of ***jquery.jqGrid.src.js***

I'm on version **jqGrid-4.4.0**

I get the error as soon as the grid loads, but before the grid is populated with data.

I'm concerned even though it works because most of my users are on IE6 and IE is very anal even about the silliest of javascript errors at times.
Any sort of help on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

PS: A couple of things I thought I'll add after reading responses to similar previously asked questions.

- [I've already set `root: "rows"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9506467/1415352)
- [I've already set `jsonReader : { repeatitems: false }`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214240/1415352)
- The JSON data I'm returning to the grid is of the structure: `{"total": "1", "records": "0", "rows": [], "page": "1"}`
- EDIT: I also just tried jqGrid-4.4.1 which is the latest version.  Still get the same error.

Comment: which exactly error and in which line you have if you use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and in which version (4.4.1 or 4.4.0)? When you get the error: during first filling of the grid with respect of the server response?

Comment: Line 4364 in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. I'm on version 4.4.0. I get the error as soon as the grid loads, i.e. before the grid is populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very strange!

The line 4364 of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of jQuery `4.4.0` is inside of `jqModal` module of jqGrid which is mostly not really required. The module should typically not used during loading of the grid. In many cases it could be not used by setting `jqModal` parameter to false.

I suppose that you have some compatibility problems with other JavaScript plugins which you use.

You can set `$.fn.jqm` to `undefined` or `null` in your code somewhere at the beginning of your code. For example you can do this directly after loading of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. As the results the module `jqModal` will be not used.

Comment: Aha! That was it! Thanks Oleg!
I remember now. I had tried everything and my modal-search box was always loading on page-load. So to force it to close, I called `$(".ui-icon-closethick").trigger('click');` And that worked but it fired that error in the console. 
This solves this issue of mine. But I still need of a clean way of not-popping my modal-search box on page-load.

Comment: @keithxm23: You are welcome! I supposed that the error produced inside of `jqmHide`. I didn't really understood from your explanation why search box should be seen during loading of the grid. Probably you wanted to implement something and implemented it not quite correctly. I suppose that the same problem can be used in another way. Why search box will be displayed?

Comment: @keithxm23: By the way you can use `jqModal: false` option of the searching box. You can set the setting globally with respect of `$.extend($.jgrid.search, {jqModal: false});`

Comment: @Oleg: I just faced similar issue with version 4.5.4 and the grid pager.
It complained about this.p is undefined when trying to access this.p.id (also related to jqModal).
The solution was to chain the pager to the grid constructor.

Comment: @syslogic: Could you provide the demo which demonstrates the problem?