# jqGrid v4.5.4 "TypeError: this.p is undefined"

Tags: jqgrid

I'm getting the above error on this line in jqGrid.src.js, line 8713:

var alertIDs = {themodal: 'alertmod_' + this.p.id, modalhead: 'alerthd_' + this.p.id,modalcontent: 'alertcnt_' + this.p.id},

this.p is null.

I see this: [jqGrid throws: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297393/jqgrid-throws-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-a-of-undefined)

but, don't understand the answer.  I am already doing this, "The solution was to chain the pager to the grid constructor."

but, still getting the error.

Comment: My code is pretty much the online demo with the URL and columns changed:

Comment: What you mean under "My code is pretty much the online demo"? Do you have your demo which produce the error available online? Which URL has the demo? The error which you describe exist typically if you either forget to include some JavaScript files of if you use jqGrid in a wrong way. The URL on the page which has the problem can explain all.

Comment: I'm having a lovely time just getting some simple code in here.  SO is kicking back with 'too long' even though it's not > 600 chars.   My code is this, http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, with the columns renamed, the caption changed and a height of 500px, and a URL that works with my server.  Default jsonReader return, data loads fine, but that exception above bombs out keeping any navGrid buttons like refresh, search, from appearing.  Debugging it, it *appears* this.p should be the grid pager, but that's undefined.  Not sure where to go from here, suggestion?

Comment: The error is in the HTML or JavaScript code which you use. If you *describe* your code you don't describe the error which you did. So the only way to find the error is to see your code. First of all you need to include `<head>` of your page with exact list of JavaScript files which you use. Seconds you should change the text of your question. Is the error exist on loading of `jqGrid.src.js` or on executing of some line of your code which you jqGrid? Could you include the line of your code?

Comment: It's during initialization, and correct you are, it is my code.  The .navGrid was chained to the wrapper around .jqGrid.  D'OH.  Thanks so much for a quick reply, sorry for cut-n-haste stupidity.

Comment: You are welcome! Your question will have any value for other visitors only if you write yourself short answer on your question where your describe which error it was and how you changed the code to fix the problem.